# How can I view the content of a USB stick on a PS4?

Tags: ps4

I'm trying to view some data that's on a USB stick in my PS4. I tried formatting the USB stick with FAT32 (4GB), but that didn't work. I tried a second one, doesn't work either... or I just don't know where to look for my data.

I tried in Settings -> Devices, but there are no storage devices it seems. So I go to Settings -> System Storage Management, nothing there either. How can I access the USB stick or how can I transfer data onto a PS4?

Comment: I don't see how this is off-topic. You can use USB sticks on the PS4 and how to access the content of the stick through the PS4 menus doesn't seem to be about "game design and development". Or did I misunderstand what this is about?

Comment: @Kodama The asker is trying to develop for a PS4, not where to find the contents through the XMB.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure where to put it, in my mind it's not a development question, there are other ps4 questions on this site obviously, so thanks for putting me on hold without explanation. @Kodama : the question is : How can I access the USB stick content? Has nothing to do with development.

Comment: If all you're really asking is how to access some data on a USB stick, I don't think that's a "development" question either. I removed those references from the question, although I'm not sure if that's sufficient to make the question on-topic here.

Comment: I voted to reopen with the edits, but just so you know, if you have any questions about the actual porting (mentioned in the original post) or any other development questions, [DameDev.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) is way better suited for those. That being said, I don't know much about porting Unity to PS4, but I have a hard time beliving that _consumer level_ file transfer methods would be sufficent.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings → Application Saved Data Management; it should be right there. I was just looking for the same info and found it out on my own. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's important, that if you are using external storage such as a second HDD, then USB Stick storage will be not read until the external disc is connected. To browse plugged Pendrive, you have to unplug HDD first. PS4 has bounded to work with only one storage (except internal HDD).